# Implement Doctrine2 Caching with PHP Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, caching, doctrine-orm, memcached

I know that GAE currently supports symfony: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world, but I am using Doctrine2 without symfony. I have read in the Doctrine docs to not use ArrayCache in production, has anyone else been able to use Memcache or ApcCache?

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html if you set `$isDevMode` to false when calling `Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration` it should automatically fall back to memcache on GAE.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I am using the Annotation configuration.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it all leads to this line https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Setup.php#L126 which causes doctrine to pick memcache.

Comment: Okay great thanks. Have you used Doctrine on GAE with Memcache successfully? I am having a hard time making it work with just the ArrayCache, so I can't test if this works or not (but when I fix it, and confirm this works I'll accept your answer). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941836/doctrine-not-finding-data-on-google-app-engine

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm not sure how this would work on GAE without being ported to the AppEngine PHP API. By default, Doctrine wants to connect to a memcached server on `127.0.0.1`, but that's not how AppEngine Memcache works: you need to use the language-specific library for it. Thus, Doctrine would need a patch to support GAE memcache properly. If you are running on Managed VMs, you can connect to a memcached server you are running yourself, but that doesn't apply to GAE, since (a) you can't spawn subprocesses, and (b) there's nothing listening on `127.0.0.1:11211`.